# How to input a Decimal value to a hidden simple form field - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have an input form built with simple_form and I need to include a decimal value hiddenly.

The value type is *decimal* (*t.decimal  "price"*)

I've tried several ways but it is not saved as an input, the field keeps empty.

My form, with several attempts, no one succesfull:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |form| %>
   <%= form.input :price, :as => "hidden", :input_html => {:type => "decimal", :value => 20 } %>

   <%= form.input :price, :as => "hidden", :input_html => { :value => "20" } %>

   <%= form.input :price, :as => "hidden", :input_html => { :value => 20 } %>
<% end %>
```

I am pretty sure it is a syntax problem, but just in case my model contains:

```
validates :price, presence: true
```

I know the decimal value is not saving because when submitting the form it checks if `@post.valid?` and it launches *can't be blank* error to the price field

Comment: You can also try hidden_field_tag. `hidden_field_tag 'post[price]', '100'`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |form| %>

    <%= form.input :price, as: :hidden,  :input_html => { :value => '20' } %>

<% end %>
```